# How would you vectorise this for loop in R (s += i/2)?

Tags: r, vectorization

```
f <- function(n){
  s <- 0
  for (i in 1:n){
    s <- s + (i/2)
  }
  print(s)
}
```

The tricky part is of course that `s` recursively depends from the previous loop..

[EDIT]

Thank you for your answers. I was just trying to verify the increment in performances using vectorisations in R compared with loops.

With n=1000000000 the above function takes 287 seconds, while both `sum((1:n)/2)` and  `sum(seq_len(n)/2)` return me an error that the system "cannot allocate a vector of size 7.5 Gb"

For comparison, the same function (with n=1000000000) in Julia takes 38 seconds (0.87 defining the type of `s`), in C++ 2.48 seconds / 0.87 compiling with optimisation and in Python 98 seconds / 0.88 using numba decorators.

Comment: Isn't this `sum(1:n)/2`?

Comment: why do you want to vectorize the loop? it's simply n*(n+1)/4, can be computed in constant time.

Comment: It also depends on your machine, I did run `sum(seq_len(n)/2)` with `n=1000000000` and I got `2.5e+17` as answer without any error. Time taken about `5.5 ` secs on average.

Comment: Try wrapping `f` with `compiler::cmpfun` to gain significant efficiency since your "f" concerns mostly interpreter overhead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this (in case `n>0`):

```
sum(seq_len(n)/2)

f(10)
#[1] 27.5

sum(seq_len(10)/2)
#[1] 27.5
```

In case `n<0`:

```
sum((1:n)/2)

n <- -11
f(n)
#[1] -32.5

sum((1:n)/2)
#[1] -32.5
```

Just a quick benchmarking:

```
library(microbenchmark)
n <- 10000

f1 <- function(n) sum(seq_len(n)/2)
f2 <- function(n){ s <- 0;for (i in 1:n){s <- s + (i/2);};s}

f1(n)==f2(n)
# [1] TRUE
microbenchmark(f1(n), f2(n))

# Unit: microseconds
  # expr      min       lq       mean   median       uq      max neval
 # f1(n)   20.733   22.235   27.51751   22.836   24.639   82.028   100
 # f2(n) 3971.008 4275.383 4517.52582 4484.510 4648.867 5867.272   100
```

Comment: @PierreLafortune a better way to put it would be "this will error out with negative numbers while the original code will **give incorrect results silently**. Because I'll bet you any money the OP has simply failed to consider negative numbers.

Comment: @989: I'd just stick with `seq_len`.

Comment: I agree with that assessment Hong Ooi

Comment: @HongOoi I added the negative case just to be covered but I also do not think its meant by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

is this what you mean?

```
n<-10
print(sum((1:n)/2))
```